# Typecasting an address to Function pointer

Tags: c, bootloader, u-boot

I have particular code which comes from u-boot, bootloader where address being typecast to function pointer but not sure for what purpose that's is being done

```
 void    (*kernel)(bd_t *, ulong r4, ulong r5, ulong r6,ulong r7, ulong r8, ulong r9);//prototype


 kernel = (void (*)(bd_t *, ulong, ulong, ulong,ulong, ulong, ulong))images->ep;
```

Is in first statement registers r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9 gets initialized when later function is called??

where images->ep is address of memory and bd_ t is bord information structure.

Can anybody let me know purpose of typing casing address into function pointer.

Comment: Because the address is the address of a function?

Comment: To call it as a function.

Comment: What's the type of `images->ep`? If it's neither one of `void (*)(bd_t *, ulong, ulong, ulong,ulong, ulong, ulong)` and `void *`, then the cast is necessary, otherwise it isn't.

Comment: Shouln't the assignment better be `*(void **) (&kernel) = (void *) images->ep;`? Otherwise `gcc` would complain about `ISO C forbids conversion of object pointer to function pointer type`.

Comment: @alk - the explicit cast makes that warning go away, at least in a quick test I made here.

Comment: @alk, sorry - GCC didn't take it with `-pedantic`, but `clang` did.

Answer (score 3):

Well, presumably they're going to call that pointer as a function at some point.  The fact that the original structure entry's name is `ep` is telling - that probably stands for "entry point".  Is there something like:

```
kernel(....) // appropriate arguments inserted
```

or

```
(*kernel)(....)
```

Found later in the code?

As you mentioned, `images->ep` is an "address of memory", which presumably means it's some kind of pointer type.  In standard C, conversions between pointer types require an explicit cast (unless one of them is `void *`).

Comment: I think OP is asking why the structure member is cast to the function pointer type in the assignment, and not why `kernel` is declared as a function pointer.

Comment: Thanks Carl for the response ,I'm more interested in knowing use case of function pointer in this particular scenario.

Comment: What do you mean by that, exactly?

Comment: I got your point ,images->ep which is nothing but address is typecast to proper pointer so that it can point to particular structure which is board information structure and later on arguments passed to function will be filled later when a call is made to this function pointer.Is this my understanding ok or you would like to add few points top of it .